# Proof maximal area of a n-polygon with Lagrange multipliers

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, lagrange-multiplier

We have an example of the discrete version of Dido's problem.

Let $n\in N$ and $n \geq 3$.

A polygon exists with $n$ sides and corners P. The corners are given by:

$P_k$ = ($r_k \cos \sigma_k$, $r_k \sin \sigma_k$) with

$r_0$=$r_n$, $\sigma_0=0$, $\sigma_k$= $\alpha_1$ +...+$\alpha_k$, $k=1,...,n$ , $\alpha_j$ $\in$ ($0,\pi$), $j=1,...,n$ and $\sigma_n = 2\pi$.

See image https://postimg.cc/dhKtgwK3.

We wrote the perimeter l and the area A as a function of the variables $r_n$ and $\alpha_n$.

len = $ \Sigma \sqrt {r_k^2+r_{k+1}^2-2r_k r_{k+1} \cos(\alpha_k)} $

and

A = $\Sigma \sqrt {P_n (P_n-r_k)(P_n-r_{k+1})(P_n - \sqrt {r_k^2 + r_{k+1}^2 -r_k r_{k+1} \cos(\alpha_k)}} $

with $P_k= r_k/2 +r_{k+1}/2 + \sqrt {r_k^2 + r_{k+1}^2 -r_k r_{k+1} \cos(\alpha_k)}/2 $.

The maximum area with a constant perimeter L needs to be found with the Lagrange equations.

We have for our Lagrange equation:

$$L(r_k,\alpha_k,\lambda,\mu)= \Sigma \nabla A_k + \lambda \nabla g + \mu \nabla h =0, $$

with $g =  \Sigma (\sqrt {r_k^2+r_{k+1}^2-2r_k r_{k+1} \cos(\alpha_k)} - len_k) $

and $h =  \Sigma (\sqrt {P_n (P_n-r_k)(P_n-r_{k+1})(P_n - \sqrt {r_k^2 + r_{k+1}^2 -r_k r_{k+1} \cos(\alpha_k)}} - A_k) $.

Now we need to solve the system of equations to find that $r_1 = ... = r_n$ and $\alpha_1 = ... = \alpha_n$ is the solution (for maximal area A given perimeter L. I cannot find this solution from the equations. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: I don't know if this would help, but you could write $l=l_1+\cdots+l_n$ and then add the constraints $l_k^2 = \cdots$. Just gets rid of the $\sqrt{}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering another formulation

for $p_k = (x_k, y_k)$ and such that $p_n = p_1$

we have

$$
A = \frac 12\left((x_2-x_1)(y_2+y_1)+(x_3-x_2)(y_3+y_2)+\cdots + (x_1-x_{n-1})(y_1+y_{n-1})\right)\\
P = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \lVert p_{k+1}-p_k\rVert
$$

so the Lagrangian reads

$$
L(p,\lambda) = A+\lambda(P-P_0)
$$

then we have

$$
L_{x_k} = \frac 12(y_k-y_{k+2})+\lambda\left(\frac{x_k-x_{k-1}}{\lVert p_k-p_{k-1}\rVert}+\frac{x_k-x_{k+1}}{\lVert p_k-p_{k+1}\rVert}\right)=0\\
L_{y_k} = \frac 12(x_{k+1}-x_{k-1})+\lambda\left(\frac{y_k-y_{k-1}}{\lVert p_k-p_{k-1}\rVert}+\frac{y_k-y_{k+1}}{\lVert p_k-p_{k+1}\rVert}\right)=0\\
L_{\lambda}=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \lVert p_{k+1}-p_k\rVert - P_0 = 0
$$

Making some numerical experiments for $n = 6$ with $P_0 = 5$ we obtained

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
x_k & y_k \\
 0.311083 & 0.401729 \\
 0.256912 & -0.596802 \\
 -0.709488 & -0.853846 \\
 -1.25258 & -0.0141751 \\
 -0.621837 & 0.761813 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

[image]